# Read data using countries module in view

Tags: 7, views

I am using the [countries module](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) to add **countries** in my content type **project**.

I create a view with **type = Default node index** to display my content.

I added the **Indexed Nœud: Countries (Countries)**

But the data saved in my field_countries is not displaying yet it is displayed well in the details page (node project).

Any idea to display the countries data in my view?

Thank you

Comment: @a-sana I haven't tried this module, but on its [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) it says you need to add a **Relationship** `Field: Country (field-country)`. After that you can add a field showing countries, this field must use the Relationship you created in order to show the countries.

Comment: @prkos, thanks for response, I added the relationship but nothing was changed

Comment: @a-sana adding a Relationship only opens the possibility for that View to add more fields and filters, it doesn't happen automatically. After you add the Relationship, you also need to add a new Field called Countries. Did you do those 2 steps listed on the module project page?

Answer (score 0):

While adding relationship with countries, **the most important**, Check the checkbox [**Require this relationship**](http://prntscr.com/jdobrm) and then add **Countries: Name** as fields you want.

It works for me ([see](http://prntscr.com/jdoela)) and hope for you too